# How does build trigger work using when condition?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In our environment, Jenkins checkout code from Gitlab repo:

Jenkinsfile snippet used to trigger docker build:

```
stage('release build') {
      agent {
          label 'label-name'
      }
    
      when {
           beforeAgent true
           environment name: "gitLabActionType", value: "TAG_PUSH"
      }
      steps{
           script{
                // read artifactory info in env
           }
           script {
                // docker build
           }
           script {
               // docker push
           }
      }
}
```

---

In the above code,

1)

Does `when` condition trigger build for every tag push on any Git branch?

2)

if yes, how to trigger build for commit push on a specific Git branch(`develop`)?

Comment: `when` condition just check your condition for running specific stage.

Answer (score 1):

`when` doesn't trigger builds, it just skips the stage when the conditions are not met.